# How to get the path or slug from a URL without optional query string parameters

Tags: javascript, regex

In the following URL examples:

```
http://something.com/hello/world/this-is-a-slug
http://something.com/hello/world/this-is-a-slug#awesome           
http://something.com/hello/world/this-is-a-slug?awesome=yes#world
/hello/world/this-is-a-slug
etc
```

I need `this-is-a-slug`

Here's what I have so far, which works when a query string is present:

```
[^/]+?(.?(?=[\?]))
```

But having issues getting this right when a query string is not present. I can get it working, but then break the one with the query string. This has to be regex, no other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expression:

```
(?<=\/)[a-z-]+(?=[#a-z?=]+$|$)
```

- `(?<=\/)` Positive lookbehind for `/`.
- `[a-z-]+` Alphabetic characters and `-`.
- `(?=[#a-z?=]+$|$)` Positive lookahead for end of string, or any characters such as `#`, `?`, `=` and alphabetic characters at the end of the string.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Hx6dBk/1).

Comment: The issue I face here is if the url has a slash after the query string or hash, it pulls the wrong value (i.e. `/some/path?hello=world#/matches-this-instead`)

Comment: Use `(?<=[a-z]\/)[a-z-]+(?=[#a-z?=]+$|$)` then? See [here](https://regex101.com/r/Hx6dBk/2).